# How to precompile assets and avoid "Error: file isn't precompiled" on specific pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, asset-pipeline

When I push my code to Heroku I get the following message:

> Precompiling assets failed, enabling runtime asset compilation

Runtime compilation can cause issues, so I added the following line to config/application.rb:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

(As suggested at [Error pushing to heroku - aborting my rake assets:precompile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712012/error-pushing-to-heroku-aborting-my-rake-assetsprecompile) and on [Heroku Help](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar#troubleshooting) )

This allows the precompilation to work. However, some of my pages include other javascript files. For example, I include a file from 'vendor/javascripts' within certain pages by putting a tag on the specific page:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "src/ace.js" %>
```

When I visit such a page, it causes the following error (when precompiling works):

> ActionView::Template::Error: src/ace.js isn't precompiled

How can I fix it so such pages do not throw errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add the file to the `assets.precompile`.

Add the following to your `config/environments/production.rb` to compile all your css/js files:

```
config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', '*.css']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your ace.js and other required files in a javascript file for instance "custom.js"
Then you can use your regular code to include the file

Add the following in **custom.js**. ( Assumed ace.js resides in vendor/javascripts)

```
//= require ace
```

Add the file to compilation list by adding following in **application.rb**

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( custom.js )
```

You can now use your javascript_tag to include the source

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "custom" %>
```