# Heroku : Postgres - could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am desperately trying to push my app to heroku but it fails with this error message.
It works on my local machine but I can't even push it to heroku.
I've been trying to make this work several days, but can't find out.

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

   Running: rake assets:precompile
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
   rake aborted!
   could not connect to server: Connection refused
   Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
   /tmp/build_6c1232cd-5bee-4760-a11c-1745627fba6e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `initialize'
   /tmp/build_6c1232cd-5bee-4760-a11c-1745627fba6e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `new'
   /tmp/build_6c1232cd-5bee-4760-a11c-1745627fba6e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `connect'
   ....
   /tmp/build_6c1232cd-5bee-4760-a11c-1745627fba6e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:93:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_6c1232cd-5bee-4760-a11c-1745627fba6e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_6c1232cd-5bee-4760-a11c-1745627fba6e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:23:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
   /tmp/build_6c1232cd-5bee-4760-a11c-1745627fba6e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
   Tasks: TOP => environment
   (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Here is my gemfile

source 'http://rubygems.org'
      ruby '2.0.0'

```
  gem 'rails', '3.2.14'
  gem 'json'
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'paymill'
  gem 'pg', "0.16.0"
  gem 'haml'
  gem 'jammit', :git => 'https://github.com/documentcloud/jammit.git', :branch => 'master'
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'aws-s3'
  gem 'aws-sdk'
  gem 'friendly_id'
  gem 'devise', '~> 2.2.7'
  gem 'activeadmin', "0.6.0"
  gem 'formtastic'
  gem 'inherited_resources'
  gem 'paperclip', '~> 2.4'
  gem 'country_select'
  gem 'coffee-script'

  group :development, :test do
    gem 'escape_utils'
    gem 'rails-footnotes'
    gem 'rack-webconsole'
    gem 'better_errors'
    gem 'binding_of_caller'
    gem 'pry'
    gem 'pry-debugger'
  end

  group :test do
    gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.1.0'
    gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.14.0'
    gem 'cucumber-rails', '~> 1.4.0', require: false
    gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.0.1'
    # gem 'capybara', '~> 2.1.0'
    gem 'simplecov', require: false
  end
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a new Heroku app and seeing if pushing it to there works?

Comment: in your database.yml under production do you have the heroku db settings?

Comment: @SamD Heroku overwrites the database configuration, so having the settings in that file is unnecessary.

Comment: When is the error occuring? On Heroku's system, or on your own? It's looking at `127.0.0.1` (localhost) -- does this mean you're precompiling on your local machine, or on the Heroku server?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've just solved this block in my app.

The trick was in the troubleshooting documentation https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#troubleshooting:

> The most common cause of failures in assets:precompile is an app that relies on having its environment present to boot. Your app’s config vars are not present in the environment during slug compilation, so you should take steps to handle the nil case for config vars (and add-on resources) in your initializers.
>
> In Rails 3.x, you can prevent initializing your application and connecting to the database by ensuring that the following line is in your config/application.rb:
>
> `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false`
>
> **Do not forget to commit to git after changing this setting.**

There is more explanation of this answer over on this tread: [Error pushing to heroku - aborting my rake assets:precompile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712012/error-pushing-to-heroku-aborting-my-rake-assetsprecompile)

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify your gemfile?

```
group :development, :test do
     gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
     gem 'pg'
     gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

So basically add those 3 gems.
Then do "bundle install" then push it to Heroku.
Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$ heroku labs:enable user-env-compile
```

The problem might caused by one of the gems is trying to connect to the database during assets precompiling. Check heroku documentation for [Heroku Labs: user-env-compile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile) to see how is this works.