# Trouble configuring Database.yml file.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, heroku

I'm setting up a viral landing page rails app using Harry's Shave club open source code.

https://github.com/wardpenney/prelaunchr/tree/master

I'm struggling to push the app to heroku and it looks like my assets aren't precompiling. I think this is because my database.yml file is setup incorrectly. Any ideas?

Here's the error when I try to compile.

```
on RAILS_GROUPS=assets
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
rake aborted!
refer/happycumar.gif isn't precompiled (this is a giff in my assets folder)
```

Here's the error when I try to push to heroku

```
   Bundle completed (52.44s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        could not connect to server: Connection refused
remote:        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
remote:        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

and

```
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !     Attempted to access a nonexistent database:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pre-provision-database
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to safe-tor-3231.
remote:
```

Here's my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'


gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'pg'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :development do
  gem 'pry'
end

gem 'rails_12factor' 
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'

gem 'unicorn'


# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger

# gem 'debugger'
```

I think I've followed the directions in the documents but am not 100% sure. Again, just due to when the error is happening, I think it has to do with the Database.yml file.

Database.yml file.:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: prelaunchr
  host: localhost

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: prelaunchr
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: prelaunchr
  host: localhost
```

It says the test database shouldn't be the same as the production and development dbs but I'm just not sure what I'd change it to, how to configure it properly, or if that's even the issue at all...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Funny what happens when you break a question down...

Found the answer here [Error pushing to heroku - aborting my rake assets:precompile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712012/error-pushing-to-heroku-aborting-my-rake-assetsprecompile)